# GetUserNameA doesn't retrieve the latest user name

Tags: vba, winapi, windows-10

I have a function which uses windows api to get current windows user login (https://support.microsoft.com/en-nz/help/152970/visual-basic-procedure-to-get-current-user-name).

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long

' Main routine to Dimension variables, retrieve user name.
Public Function WindowsUserName() As String

     ' Dimension variables
     Dim lpBuff As String * 25
     Dim ret As Long, UserName As String

     ' Get the user name minus any trailing spaces found in the name.
     ret = GetUserName(lpBuff, 25)
     WindowsUserName = Left(lpBuff, InStr(lpBuff, Chr(0)) - 1)

End Function
```

Problem: if I renamed the windows user (in Windows 10), this function always get the old name, even though I login with the new name.

Is there anyway to retrieve the latest user name in VBA?

Updated: In few comments, the account name changed in Control Panel is display name, not user name. Now back to my question: Is there anyway to retrieve the latest DISPLAY name in VBA?

Comment: Why you want to rename a windows user?... From my understanding it’s not possible to get a changed login-name this way without restarting your OS. A dll is usually written when compiled and I guess this happens after login to windows.

Comment: Maybe the memory isn’t updated, which is accessed to get the userName.

Comment: Code is working for me. However I did not change the username I just logged on with another user.

Comment: You've changed the display name rather than the system username. I'm not even sure if you can change the latter.

Comment: 1) After I changed the user name, I restarted the OS & login with the new name. Still the old name retrieved.
2) Sure it works if login as "another" user. But my scenario is rename an existing user.
3) I used Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts\Change Your Name to change the "account name", not merely the display name.

Comment: You can also use `CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName`. It will probably return the same name, but it's shorter. :)

Comment: or simply WindowsUserName=Environ("username")

Comment: I did as the OP did and he is right. Even with all the methods used [here](https://www.devhut.net/2018/04/12/vba-recognize-user-get-username/) you still get the old name.

Comment: Did you reboot the system? What is shown when calling `set username` in a command prompt?

Comment: @len Change account name via `Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts\Change` just change display name for me. I can't use this new name to login. But when I use the old name to login the new name will display on welcome screen. So can you sure you can use the new name to login? I test on Windows 10 1903.

Comment: And `set username` still return the old name after I change the name and reboot.

Comment: @Rita Han - MSFT Mine is 1903 as well. Yes, set username will show the old name. But in Windows login/welcome screen, the new name is in the list instead of old name. I just use the new name (click to select) to login.

Comment: @len I found there are something changed in user accounts management from OS Build 18362.356 to 18362.418. From your control panel path of change the user name I can see you use OS Build 18362.418, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences in user account management between OS Build 18362.356 and 18362.418. (There are [some other versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4517211/windows-10-update-kb4517211) between these two. I didn't test those versions.)

**On OS Build 18362.356** you can see the below UI and settings. You can change the user name via `Control Panel\User Accounts\User Accounts -> Manage User Accounts -> Properties`. Either you change other account user name as a administrator or change your logged in account user name. After restart you can get the new user name using `GetUserName` API or command `set username`.

[image]

**On OS Build 18362.418** you can see the below UI and settings. Based on your description you seems using this build version and result in this issue. I can also reproduce this issue on this build version.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**On OS Build 18362.449** has the same UI and settings with 18362.356 as I showed above and I can't reproduce this issue on this build version.